# ¿Qué están haciendo throw exception y las bibliotecas en este programa de Java?

Tags: java, excepciones

Tengo este simple programa:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Problema4 {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5withRSA"); //Inicialización de MessageDigest en MD5
        SortedMap<String, String> usuarios = new TreeMap<>(); //Inicialización de TreeMap
        String usuario; //Usuario a guardar en Map
        String comprobacion;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
            System.out.print("Cree un nombre de usuario: ");
            usuario = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Cree una contraseña: ");
            String contraseña = scanner.nextLine(); //Contraseña a codificar y guardar
            byte[] hash = md.digest(contraseña.getBytes());
            if (usuarios.containsKey(usuario)) { //Elimina cualquier repetición de llave
                usuarios.remove(usuario);
                System.out.println("Ya existe un usuario con ese nombre.");
                i--;
            }
            usuarios.put(usuario, new String(hash, "UTF-8")); //Se guarda la codificación
        }
        
        for (Object x : usuarios.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(x); 
        }
        
        System.out.print("Comprueba si la contraseña existe: ");
        comprobacion = scanner.nextLine();
        byte[] hash = md.digest(comprobacion.getBytes());
        comprobacion = new String(hash, "UTF-8");
        if (usuarios.containsValue(comprobacion)) {
            System.out.println("La contraseña ya existe.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("La contraseña no existe. ");
        }
    }
}
```

El programa está funcionando, me encripta la contraseña y puedo comprobar si está siendo repetida después. Sin embargo, no entiendo bien cómo funciona "throws" y la inclusión de las bibliotecas que contienen esas excepciones. Leí que estas bibliotecas otorgan la habilidad de realizar ciertas acciones como el uso de MessageDigest y el uso del formato UTF-8, pero ¿por qué debería usar "throws" para las excepciones si en teoría el programa tiene la habilidad de realizar estas cosas? Si ya están implementados los métodos ¿por qué tengo que hacer exception handling?

Comment: Investiga acerca de "checked exceptions".

Comment: *"Si ya están implementados los métodos ¿por qué tengo que hacer exception handling?"* -> Precisamente porque estás usando esos métodos necesitas añadir ese `throws`. Ese `throws`no significa que tu código vaya a salir con una excepción si o si, es solo un "aviso" de que es posible que ese código genere ese tipo de excepciones. Un aviso que obliga a quien llame a esos métodos a añadir un catch para esas excepciones, para ser exactos (o relanzarlas). Como te han dicho, busca lo que son las checked exception en java para más información

Answer (score 1):

El throws se añade en tu método porque hay líneas de código que el método que es utilizada en ella pueden llegar a dar esas excepciones de las cuales se han de gestionar en java, si desea eliminar el throws del metodo lo que puedes introducir en el codigo es:

```
try{
código con posible excepción
} catch (<tipo de excepción> e){

}
```

Y básicamente como antes dije la clase Exception gestiona esos posible errores de ejecución.

Como ejemplo si quisieras abrir un fichero tanto para leer como escribir es posible darse el caso de que el fichero no exista, entonces se lanzaría una excepción del tipo FileNotFoundException. Y lo debería gestionar el programador diciendo que debería hacer cuando no exista el fichero que queremos abrir.